# IconButton onClick event kicks in onLoad react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below `IconButton` getting displayed right next to each and every row so for each row I can do a different API call. These buttons' alert gets displayed onLoad?! How can I fix it?

```
<IconButton onClick={alert("abc")}>
  <Edit color="action" />
</IconButton>
<IconButton onClick={alert("abc")}>
  <Update color="action" />
</IconButton>
<IconButton onClick={alert("abc")}>
  <Delete color="action" />
</IconButton>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling the function in your onClick which is why it gets triggered onLoad

You can use the es6 arrow function

```
<IconButton onClick={() => alert("abc")}>
  <Edit color="action" />
</IconButton>
<IconButton onClick={() => alert("abc")}>
  <Update color="action" />
</IconButton>
<IconButton onClick={() => alert("abc")}>
  <Delete color="action" />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: () =>  makes sense! Thanks!